# How is this form created in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, forms-services

[image]

How does one build an interactive form like this in SharePoint 2010?

Also, how do you have it so you can add multiple "Risk Owners" for example to the main record.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using Microsoft Office InfoPath, you can tell by looking at the URL.

And in InfoPath there are "repeating" functions that allow you to do the second bit.

Comment: Ok thanks... I noticed "Business Intelligence" in the URL.  Is that something that needs to be installed in Central Admin?

Comment: The business intelligence text is just the name of the library holding this form. The hint that give it away is the FormServer.aspx piece which is an enterprise SharePoint feature that allows for InfoPath forms to be published and used in the browser.